# Does OpenGL not support shared contexts on windows?

Tags: opengl, share

I am working on a cross platform OpenGL project and it seems that all of the textures that share a GLcontext have trouble when I try and load them in windows.  I have been told that this was not supported in older versions of OpenGL on windows but it seems that there must be some way to share texture resources in OpenGL on Windows.  If there was no way to share textures between multiple objects in opengl on windows this would be an unbearable bottleneck for certain applications so I assume this limitation must have been overcome by now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course it does. The method to use is called `wglShareLists` which is a bit confusing.

Each context will still have its own render state etc. This only applies to data.

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to share resources for more than 2 OpenGL contexts?

Comment: I found the answer on MSDN: any number of rendering contexts can share a single display-list space